# optimizing nested dictionary comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary comprehension that works, however I'm  not sure if it is very readable/understandable (since I don't understand it well, but i'm a noob).

Data structures:

```
dict1 = {'this key 1':['this is a comment','this too','finally this'],
      'this key 2':['this is a comment2','this too2','finally this2'],
      'this key 3':['this is a comment3','this too3','finally this3']}                                                          

list1 = ['BlIb','vILB','vliH']
```

Desired output:

```
{'BlIb':{'this key 1':['this is a comment','this too','finally this']},
'vILB':{'this key 2':['this is a comment2','this too2','finally this2']},
'vliH':{'this key 3':['this is a comment3','this too3','finally this3']}}
```

Dictionary comprehensions:

As I said above, this one works, but I'm not sure how readable it is, or if I completely understand the inner dict comprehension (using 'key' twice)

```
all_data = {idx:{key:dict1[key]} for idx,key in zip(list1,dict1)}
```

**Would this be the best way to do it?** and if so could you **explain** this part{key:Dict[key]}?

**And if not, how would you do it?**

I've also tried the below, but just adds all three of the Dict items for each List item

```
all_data = {idx: {key:value for (key,value) in dict1.items()} for idx in list1}
```

Comment: Honestly that is a pretty readable comprehension. The way to improve readability here is improve naming (ex "all_data", "list1") to clarify what is the purpose of that  "desired output" format. Right now I would describe that operation as "zip_keyvals_with_list1()". So if there's more context you should use that in your names and your code will be much more readable.

Comment: Yeah, all the data is not what I'm actually working with, nor are the variable names (e.g. list1). Just thought I would try to simplify. Could you explain why the {key:dict1[key]} part works? and maybe why the other one doesn't work?

Comment: {key:dict1[key]} is a dict literal. The other one doesn't work because you're not zipping. If you want to understand nested comprehensions, check out the official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions

Comment: Hmm, how is it a dict literal? why are you able to use key twice? and what purpose does the [] serve? Thanks for the help

Comment: `[]` (aka getitem) in the context of dictionaries is discussed in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). And for example `{'a': dict1['a']}` is a valid dict literal even though it uses the key `'a'` twice

Comment: What would dict1 look like for this? (assuming you're not talking about the dict1 in my code)?